# Loop through column values from one sheet and paste COUNTIF value from another column into another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets in an Excel file and need to perform a COUNTIF formula from one sheet and paste the respective information in another sheet. The original sheet just has the type in 1st column with an empty 2nd column. I am trying to loop through the Type from Sheet 1, in each increment loop through the Type from Sheet 2, and past the Count of column 2 from Sheet 2 into Column 2 of sheet 1.

My current VBA code is as follows:

```
Sub TestOE()
    'For loop to go until end of filled cells in 1st column of each sheet
    a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    b = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Loop
    For i = 2 To a
        For j = 2 To b
            If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1).Value Then
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B:B"), 1)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

This code is only pasting 0's in the desired outcome on Sheet 1.

Sheet to extract information from
[image: Sheet to extract information from]

Sheet to paste information in
[image: Main Sheet to paste information in]

Desired Outcome in destination sheet
[image: Desired Outcome in main sheet]

Comment: I also had a previous version of the code that would produce the same COUNTIF outcome for all types, because it would COUNT all of the binary values. However, I only want it to count the values for that specific type.

Comment: Why not use a pivot table?

Comment: @Ryan If one of the solutions satisfy your need, please accept the answers.. if all the answers doesn't work for you, Kindly drop a comment to share what difficulties you'd faced...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use sumif function to sum the values based on criteria.

here is the formula

=COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$20,Sheet2!A2)

if you want to sum the col B then

=SUMIF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$20,Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$20)

Answer (score 0):

In a few steps, you can accomplish what you want without VBA, and just use a pivot table. Just do as follows.

1. Select your [data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vx4u9.png), including the header.
2. Click on insert tab, then PivotTable. [See example for Office 365](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCz9u.jpg)
3. Since you want a different worksheet, set PivotTable to be "New Worksheet" [See example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQcEM.jpg)
4. You'll need to drag the TYPE field into the rows, and binary into the values. CountIF is the same as summing binary, so you can leave as sum. [See Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQqu6.jpg)

And you'll have an output nearly identical to what you're looking for:
[image: Final Result]